# Header cut off on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress

The header is being cut off on mobile devices, this is causing the top of the logo to be cut off. The issue occurs on this website: http://development.blackcountrydesigns.co.uk

I am building a custom theme for the website. This issue does not appear when inspected in browser tools, only when actually viewing on a mobile device. Tested on an iPhone 6 and Sony Xperia XZ1.

Here is my `header.php` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0'>

    <title><?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <header>
        <div class='bravo-logo'>
            <?php if(function_exists('the_custom_logo') && has_custom_logo()) { 
                the_custom_logo();
             } else { ?>
                <a href='<?php get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>'><?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
             <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class='bravo-main-menu bravo-menu'>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'item-spacing' => 'discard')); ?>
        </div>

        <div class='bravo-mobile-menu'>
            <i class='fas fa-bars fa-2x' id='bravo-hamburger'></i>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class='bravo-vertical-nav'>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'item-spacing' => 'discard')); ?>
    </div>
```

Here is all of the relevant CSS for my header - please note there are approximately 600 lines of CSS so I have just stripped the file and only included CSS that is relevant to the site header:

```
/* Global/General Styles */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    padding-bottom: 270px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/* Header */
header {
    min-height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #1abc9c;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Logo */
div.bravo-logo {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

div.bravo-logo img {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    div.bravo-logo img {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

div.bravo-logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #4d4d4d;
}

/* Menus */
div.bravo-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.bravo-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.bravo-main-menu {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 3.5rem;
}

div.bravo-main-menu ul {
    float: right;
}

div.bravo-main-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: .15rem;
    transition: .3s;
}

div.bravo-main-menu li.current-menu-item a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.bravo-main-menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
}

div.bravo-mobile-menu {
    display: none;
    margin-right: 1.75rem;
}

div.bravo-mobile-menu i {
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.bravo-vertical-nav {
    display: none;
}

div.bravo-vertical-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

div.bravo-vertical-nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .85rem 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1abc9c;
}

div.bravo-vertical-nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1abc9c;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1160px) {
    header {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    div.bravo-main-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    div.bravo-mobile-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
    body {
        padding-bottom: 570px;
    }

    header {
        margin-top: -32px !important;
    }

    div#wpadminbar {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 782px) {
    header {
        margin-top: -46px !important;
    }
}
```

The negative margin top that I've set on two breakpoints is to get rid of the space left when hiding the admin bar - I have tried with and without these values and neither has seemed to make a difference. I have tried adjusting the padding on the header and logo containers, but I'm struggling as I can't seem to replicate the errors within my desktop browser.

Please see below a screenshot of the issue:

[image: cut-off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by `bravo.css?ver=0.0.1`, line `483`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 782px) {
  header {
    margin-top: -46px !important;
  }
}
```

... which overrides the rule set at line `456` (same file):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
  header {
    margin-top: -32px !important;
  }
}
```

You probably want to set a different value for that `margin-top`. `-10px` looks like a good candidate.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I thought this (and the other breakpoints -32px) might be the issue, originally I added `padding-top: 46px` to the header within the same rule, refreshed my cache on mobile and no difference - perhaps a cache problem on my phone?

Comment: Yes, refreshing a website on a mobile phone can be quite a test of patience. :) I can assure you I have good development tools and I'm certain that's the cause. Set it to `0` (or even `-10px`) and you'll see it's no longer cut-off.

Comment: Ok, I think it was just me being impatient then! I will make the changes again and wait a bit longer! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I only tested on an Android (I'm on windows atm) but there's nothing in your code that I can see which should make it behave differently on IoS devices. It's only a matter of device width (@media query).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong when hiding admin bar, you don't need that negative `margin-top`, leave it at 0.

Install "remove admin bar" plugin or add `add_filter(‘show_admin_bar’, ‘__return_false’);` to `functions.php` for properly hiding it when logged in.